# rails 3: in a Class method self.do_something() how do I access an ApplicationHelper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

My model, Widget.rb,  has `include ApplicationHelper` and my instance methods have no trouble using any method defined in application_helper.rb

However, when I try to use one of the helper methods in any of my class methods such as

```
def self.send_broadcast(guid)
   track_guids(guid) # defined in application_helper.rb
end
```

I get No Method error.

Is there some secret handshake to permit use of a ApplicationHelper method inside a class method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationHelper` is just a module:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def track_guids(something)

  end
end

class Widget
  extend ApplicationHelper

  def self.send_broadcast(guid)
    track_guids(guid)
  end
end
```

Now you should have access to the module methods from a class method.  I'm not sure if you can both extend and include the same module though... not really sure what that'd do.

Edit to add:

I'm not sure what will happen if you try both extending and including the same module into the class.  With `extend` you get the module included at the class-level, with `include` it is included at the instance-level.  It might give you the methods at both class and instance if you do both... or it might die horribly.  Give it a try?

Comment: awesome, thank you, very useful response. BTW I have both include and extend and it SEEMS to be working fine.

Comment: fwiw found this article http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can access instance methods unless self is an instance. You could make an instance of Widget and call a class method from that, or you could try to call the methods from the module directly.

Comment: as a workaround for now, I simply turned the class method into an instance method and then I invoke the (former class method) method with a dummy instance, but yech.